# VB.NET TXT Files - Taking Multiple Qualifying Rows From TXT --> One SQL Server Row

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, dataset

I want to know what the name of the "thing" is that I should be searching for.  I'm trying to teach myself how to take a .txt file using VB.NET and group data like so:

TXT File has rows like:

```
WorkTypeA     FirstName    ID123
WorkTypeA     LastName     ID123
WorkTypeA     PhoneNum     ID123
WorkTypeA     FirstName    ID987
WorkTypeA     LastName     ID987
WorkTypeA     PhoneNum     ID987
```

End result in SQL Server (data is now all in into one row for each ID)

```
FirstName     LastName     PhoneNum     ID123
FirstName     LastName     PhoneNum     ID987
```

So...parsing those multiple .TXT rows and allocating into one SQL Server row using some matching criteria...what is this called?

I've learned that I can use datasets in my code to create tables in memory that I can use to put the data on to, then commit it to SQL Server when done.  But I'm having trouble locating the term to search for to help teach me how to properly find the matching data across multiple .TXT rows and get "one entry" to insert into SQL.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Should be just a case of using a for...next loop to search through your temporary datatable for the matching row, or running an UPDATE command for each incoming row. I can't think of suitable search terms other than "database normalization" or "3rd normal form" (but they aren't exactly what you are after)

Comment: Create a class to store the data.  Store each item in a Dictionary(of String, Person) where `Id###` is the key.  This will allow you to accumulate the data as you want.  Next step is the DB insert

Comment: Getting sidetracked by other projects.  Still haven't been able to come back and begin poking around with your suggestions, but wanted to say thank you very much.  Think I get all the relevant apps at home and setup a home area so I can play with this in my off time.  Anyway, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest looking up VIEW and/or DERIVED TABLES along with OPENROWSET.

Using Views:

The OPENROWSET would allow you to open the text file for querying directly within your SQL. This would enable you to import your various text files directly into tables which mimic the structure of the file. Then, you could define VIEWS which return limited data from the full table (i.e. only FirstName values, only LastName values, etc.). Finally, by writing a single query which JOINS the views together by their common field (e.g. the ID field), you can return the individual data elements in their own column.

Using SubQueries:

Essentially the same as the VIEW operation with the following differences: Instead of importing the full file into a table and defining views against that table, replace the views with SUBQUERY statements using OPENROWSET which filter the data from the text file in a similar fashion (i.e. only FirstName, only LastName, etc.). The join and returned values would be very similar in nature.

Hopefully this answer gives you a direction in which to start looking. It is far from complete and represents a simple, direct approach to starting to learn elements of SQL.

Comment: Getting sidetracked by other projects.  Still haven't been able to come back and begin poking around with your suggestions, but wanted to say thank you very much.  Think I get all the relevant apps at home and setup a home area so I can play with this in my off time.  Anyway, thanks again!